# sending soap request with an XML template with WIREMOCK (in java)

Tags: java, soap, request, wiremock

I just started to use `WIREMOCK` and trying to send a request with an `XML template` in `Java`. I saw some examples with `JSON` but I couldn't find any with `Java`.
(I mean creating the request template with `XML file` and sending it to the web service.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the contents as content body in a simple HttpURLConnection

Sample code:

```
URL endpoint = null;

endpoint = new URL("https://someurlhere.com");

conn = (HttpURLConnection) endpoint.openConnection();

// Set the necessary header fields

//The SOAPAction is required to be blank
/*The presence and content of the SOAPAction header field can be used by servers such as firewalls to appropriately
filter SOAP request messages in HTTP. The header field value of empty string ("") means that the intent of the SOAP
message is provided by the HTTP Request-URI. No value means that there is no indication of the intent of the message.*/
conn.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
//Telling the server not to Skip the SOAPAction. It's a mandatory field when we send SOAP Requests.
conn.addRequestProperty("Skip SOAP Action", "false");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

//We use POST because we are sending data to the server
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
//This is required to read response from Server
conn.setDoOutput(true);
//The server has 5 seconds to respond. Else, a timeout occurs and the connection is terminated.
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

// Send the request
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(xmlContent);
wr.flush();


// Read the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String temp;

//Reading as long as there is response to read
while ((temp = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response += temp;
}
```

As you can see, we are sending a string called xmlContent to the server. Set the content with the xml file of your choice, and it would work.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a more simple solution that can be done with wiremock, but that can help too. Thank you so much for your effort :).